# Handling attachment in composer file

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have a requirement where the asset has the multiple attributes.
For example, if asset has an attachment attribute, how to handle it?

Like `String , Integer`, do we any type or reference to handle?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the use case is. - if an asset has multiple attachments associated, can't it be an array? See https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/cto_language.html:  as in, an array of attachment references (presumably) to BLOBs or such like? All types in Hyperledger Composer model language may be declared as array.